# Does Amazon RDS Support Clustering for Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have researched online and sent a contact email to Amazon but still have not found the answer for sure. It seems the answer is no but I need to make sure.

Also, can I switch from a smaller instance to a larger instance to increase processors and memory on the fly/live with Amazon RDS for SQL Server?

I know I can do all this with Amazon RDS for MySql but I get the feeling that Amazon does not have as robust support for Sql Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon does not support these features for Sql Server:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=141240#

Answer (score 1):

No it is not supported.

Why? For a few reasons, specifically (and at the time I am writing this):

1. There are network limitations in AWS, for instance you can connect to a clustered IP address.
2. Lack of a shared disk resource required by traditional SQL clusters.
3. Incompatibility of multicast traffic. EC2/VPC does not support multicast or broadcast.

Hope this info helps!